# How to typeset Hess' Cycle in tikz-cd?

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd, chemistry

I want something like this:

```
                A        B
       ΔH        \       /
    (-397*2)      \     /
                     C
```

Where the arrow points from `A` to `C`, and from `B` to `C`.

How can I do this with `tikz-cd`?

I now know how to do this using aliases, how can I do this without alias

Comment: While I know [Hess' law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hess%27s_law) I must confess I don't really understand what the diagram should look like in the end... a picture similar to the one in the link I provided is doable with `chemfig` and probably also with `tikz-cd`

Comment: I don't see the link you provided?

Comment: Click on the words »Hess' law« in my previous comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is quite vague which is why I was hesitating to post an answer. But I suspect (unless you're actually using `A`, `B`, and `C` as compounds) the answer will be “I'd use [`chemfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig)”, anyway...

Chemical schemes can be typeset fairly easy with [`chemfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) once you understand how the `\arrow` command works.

The [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package can be used for numbers with units, the [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) package provides a lot of additional goodies for chemists. (For example the `\Enthalpy` macro).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}% for the scheme mechanism, uses TikZ
\usepackage{chemmacros}% for the \ch command, also loads `siunitx'
\begin{document}

\schemestart
  \ch{C\sld{} + 2 H2O\gas}
  \arrow{->[\SI{90.1}{\kilo\joule}]}[,1.5]
  \ch{CO2\gas{} + 2 H2\gas}
  \arrow{<-[][*{0.north west}\SI{-393.5}{\kilo\joule}]}[-125,2]
  \ch{C\sld{} + 2 H2\gas{} + O2\gas}
  \arrow(@c3--@c1){->[][*{0.north east}\SI{-483.6}{\kilo\joule} ]}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to add arrows from first line to second from specific species? I'd like to have one arrow to link the two "C(s)", one arrow to link "H_2O" to "H_2" and one arrow to link the whole equation below to the right part of equation above "CO_2 + 2 H_2".